# How can I upload both zip and targz distributions to PyPI?

Tags: python, package, libraries, pypi

I can upload my package to PyPI using the following command:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

This would create a `.zip` file (because I'm on Windows).

However I'd like to have both `.zip` and `.targz` files in PyPI, to easily support both Windows and Linux users.

How can I (preferably with one command) build both kinds of distributions and upload them to PyPI?

Comment: The container format `.zip` and `.tar.gz` should be fine for both systems.

Answer (score 1):

The container format `.zip` and `.tar.gz` should be handled the same on both systems.

The [documentation](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-distribution-package) doesn't specify that there is a specific archive format, so I'd assume you don't need to worry.

> Distribution Package
>
> > A versioned archive file that contains Python packages, modules, and other resource files that are used to distribute a Release. The archive file is what an end-user will download from the internet and install.
>
> ...

Comment: I think the alternate formats may be useful so that if someone downloads (manually) through the pypi page they see their 'friendly' archive type. (Many windoze people seem to wince when they see tar.gz instead .zip). For installing through pip though I think you're right that the archive type makes no difference.